# How to specify port number when sending mail with postfix?

Tags: email, smtp, port, postfix-mta

I've uncommented the 'submission' line in master.cf and I can 'telnet example.com 587' on my mail server with no problem but how do I send mail from the command line of the client to the postfix server over port 587?

My server is hosted as a digitalocean droplet (centos instance) on the internet and my client is my home laptop.

Each time I try to deliver a message with the 'mail user@example.com' command I instantly receive a rejection message because my isp blocks port 25.

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

`mail` command will drop the mail to the `SMTP` server running on your home laptop and the SMTP server running on your home laptop is not configured i guess. So it is trying to deliver the mail by doing an MX lookup (i.e to port 25 of your MX server). If you want to do any smtp tests please try using `swaks` tool.

```
# For eg. to authenticate and send mail from your mail server, you will have to use
swaks -f you@example.com -t someone@yahoo.com -s example.com -p 587 --auth-user you@example.com --auth-pass somepass
# -f from
# -t to
# -s server
# -p port
# --auth-user username 
# --auth-pass password
```

More info [here](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will definitely give it a try. I'm surprised there is no way to specify it with the 'mail' command for instance like 'mail user@example.com -p 587' What if I wanted to use this as the default config for my organisation, would all my employees be forced to communicate using 'swaks'?

Comment: `swaks` tool is best for debugging smtp issues. what is your current requirement? You want all your users to authenticate and send mails through your `example.com:587` server? in that case, why can't your users configure their mail clients to point to `example.com:587`? if scripts want to send mails, then you can use `swaks`. and if you want to use `mail` command then you will need to configure the `smtp` server running on all the client machines to autheticate and send mails using your `example.com:587` server.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, still got some learning to do it seems :)